TexStudio/Zotero/BibTex \cite not working
I'm about to write my PhD Thesis using Texstudio but I'm having great trouble in figuring out how to make \cite work. I use Zotero for the bibliography where I have installed Bibtex. I'm exporting my bib file in Better Biblatex format. I saved the bib file in the same folder as the latex documents. I'm typing for example \parencite{davisTechnologyAcceptanceModel1986} and I get (davisTechnologyAcceptanceModel1986) as output.
This is my preamble:
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.7cm,right=2.7cm,top=3.00cm,bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage [main=english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,citestyle=apa]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{references.bib} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

my document:
\begin{document}
    
    \pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{7}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsc{\nouppercase{{\leftmark}}}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{}

\tableofcontents

    
    \listoffigures
    
    \listoftables
    
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \phantomsection
    \vspace*{1.95cm} \hspace*{-0.155cm} %,88
    \textbf{{\Huge List of Abbreviations}\\}
    \vspace*{0.5cm}     
    \begin{acronym}[WWWW]
        \acro{AI}{Artificial Intelligence}
        \acro{TAM}{Technology Acceptance Model}
        \acro{UTAUT}{Unified Theory of Acceptance and Use of Technology}
    \end{acronym}
    
    \newpage
    
\pagenumbering{arabic}  

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Title}

Citation example \parencite{davisTechnologyAcceptanceModel1986}

\end{document}

And my references.bib file:
@thesis{davisTechnologyAcceptanceModel1986,
  title = {A {{Technology Acceptance Model}} for {{Empirically Testing New End-User Information Systems}}: {{Theory}} and {{Results}}},
  author = {Davis, F.D.},
  date = {1986}
}

@article{dwivediEmpiricalValidationUnified2017,
  title = {An Empirical Validation of a Unified Model of Electronic Government Adoption ({{UMEGA}})},
  author = {Dwivedi, Yogesh K. and Rana, Nripendra P. and Janssen, Marijn and Lal, Banita and Williams, Michael D. and Clement, Marc},
  date = {2017},
  journaltitle = {Government Information Quarterly},
  volume = {34},
  number = {2},
  pages = {211--230},
  doi = {10.1016/j.giq.2017.03.001}
}

I'm posting a screenshot

Any suggestions how to work this out?

you are using biblatex so need to use biber not bibtex to generate the bibliography. Unrelated but don't use OT1 encoding. Unfortunately it is the default so specifying it does nothing but it is better to specify (any) other encoding, such as T1

"Options" => "Configure TeXStudio" => "Build" => "Bibliography Tool" => "Biber"

I checked the bibliography tool and it is Biber. I found out though that there isn't any .blg file. I see that this has already been answered. Thank you all.
